# Parse HTML into text with Div level in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scripting

```
library(XML)
html <- read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1011290/000114036105007405/body.htm")
doc.html = htmlTreeParse(html, useInternal = TRUE)
doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(doc.html, '//div', xmlValue))
```

The above code reads text twice because of div level/structure, I need to read text only once. Thank you for your time and help. i.e.

> doc.text[2] # contains all the text which repeats again in 3 to 59

Comment: What if you just read the first `div`? `'//div[1]'`

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a regex question...

Comment: Are you sure you are employing XML? The function read_html is likely from rvest, it is not from XML.

Comment: I want all the text inside document but just once not repeated. I have seen some approach to achieving this is to use a smart regular expression which matches anything between “<” and “> just a thought to tag regex if any one can help with it

Comment: I don't know much about R, yap its my mistake was trying different approaches to get desired results @NicolásVelásquez

Comment: No worries mate. This is the right social network to come to learn and make mistakes so we learn to correct them. XML's xmlParse and xmlTreeParse might not yield exact equivalents of what you'd get with rvest read_html. 

So it would be useful for the community to know that to reproduce your exmaple we need to load the object called 'html' through the function read_html from the package rvest.

Comment: thanks for your time and help @NicolásVelásquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
html <- read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1011290/000114036105007405/body.htm")
text <- html %>% 
         html_nodes(xpath = "//text/div") %>%
         html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
         paste( collapse = ' ')
```

Comment: much better and preserved with levels > text = paste(text, collapse = ' ') < just an addition working perfectly.

Comment: just for the knowledge, how to figure out xpath = "//text/div" don't know much about R and its packages

Comment: In this case it was just an educated guess mad by exploring the page's source code. A good tutorial is here: http://www.bernhardlearns.com/2017/04/webscraping-with-r-and-rvest-how-can-i.html Just note that this tutorial employs CSS selectors rather than XPATH. In most cases they are equivalent.